# How do I pass the Unicode select from Java to my database

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I am working on a dictionary Java web app with multiple languages. The database I'm using is SQL Server 2019. This time, the operation is to return the Japanese word from the database when the user searches for it either by Japanese characters (hiragana, katakana, kanji if you are familiar with them) or roman letters (letters like a, b, c we are accustomed to in English). When I execute this query in SQL Server it works just fine:

`Select j.Word, j.Romaaji, p.PoS, d.[Definition], d.Example from Japanese j join (DefinitionsJP d join PartOfSpeech p on d.PoSID = p.PoSID ) on j.WordID = d.WordID where j.Word = N'ano' or j.Romaaji = 'ano'`

The result:

[image: the table returns the record I need]

However, when I apply this query to Java, it doesn't seem to work (i.e. doesn't return anything to list)

```
public ArrayList<Word> getWordJP(String searchStr) {
        ArrayList<Word> list = new ArrayList<Word>();
        try {
            String strSelect = "Select j.Word, j.Romaaji, p.PoS, d.[Definition], d.Example from Japanese j \n"
                    + "join (DefinitionsJP d join PartOfSpeech p on d.PoSID = p.PoSID ) \n"
                    + "on j.WordID = d.WordID where j.Word = N? or j.Romaaji = ?";
            stm = cnn.prepareStatement(strSelect);
            stm.setString(1, searchStr);
            stm.setString(2, searchStr);
            rs = stm.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Word w = new Word();
                w.word = rs.getString("Word");
                w.romaaji = rs.getString("Romaaji");
                w.PartOfSpeech = rs.getString("PoS");
                w.Definition = rs.getString("Definition");
                w.Example = rs.getString("Example");
                list.add(w);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("getWordJP fail:" + e.getMessage());
        }
        return list;
    }
```

I believe the `j.Word = N?` is the part that is causing me the problem because when I tried to remove it, the query works fine again. As to why the 'N' is there, well, in SQL Server, when you try to select a Unicode record, such as a Japanese or Mandarin character, you need to add an N before the select string like N'あの' in order for it to work. Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Well, I finally figured it out. I thought to delete this post but others might get into the same issue so I decided not to. So here's how you make it works.

simply remove the "N?" from the query like so:

```
where j.Word = ?
```

also, make this adjustment to your setString statement:

```
stm.setString(1, "N" + searchStr);
```

and voila, that should be it. Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: I very much doubt that `"N" + searchStr` is correct.  What if `searchStr` contains "one"?  You’ll be doing a query for the string "None".  Generally, it is the JDBC driver’s responsibility to craft a proper SQL query based on the data you provide, and that includes N'text' arguments where needed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).